# Says I am missing semicolon, I am not

Tags: javascript

I new to JS and am making a small math game. On JSHint it says I am missing a semicolon on a line, and I am not, and it will not run in my browser, I will post the code, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

```
var newMathGame = function() {
    var points = 1;
    var numberOfQuestions = prompt("How many questions would you like?");
    var highestNumber = prompt(
        "What is the highest number you would like to be quizzed on?");
    var whichGame = prompt(
        "Would you you like to play\n 'SUBTRACTION', 'ADDITION', 'MULTIPLICATION' or 'DIVISION'?"
    ).toUpperCase();
    switch (whichGame) {
        case 'ADDITION':
            addition();
            break;
        case 'SUBTRACTION':
            subtraction();
            break;
        case 'DIVISION':
            division();
            break;
        case 'MULTIPLICATION':
            multiplication();
            break;
    }

    function subtraction() {
        for (var count = 0; count < numberOfQuestions; count++) {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            if (x < y) {
                subtraction();
            } else {
                var answer = (x - y);
                var user_answer = prompt(x + "-" + y);
                if (answer == user_answer) {
                    alert("Yes!");
                } else {
                    alert("No! The answer is " + answer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function addition() {
        for (var count = 0; count < numberOfQuestions; count++) {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            var answer = (x + y);
            var user answer = (x + "+" + y); //says I am missing semicolon on this line
            if (answer == user_answer) {
                alert("Yes!");
            } else {
                alert("No! The answer is " + answer);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Writing in sentences would make your question easier to read. More importantly, actually reading your code and the error message would help you avoid posting questions like this that show no real effort and immediately get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable name `user answer` is invalid because it has a space. Looks like it should be `user_answer`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the variable is called `user_answer` before, and yet your line says the variable to check is called `user answer`. JavaScript and many other compilers use one-word variables. To get the compiler to stop flipping out, add an underscore where the error is so it says `user_answer`.

Answer (score 1):

This line is syntactically incorrect. Variable names can not contain spaces.

```
var user answer = (x + "+" + y);
```

The debugger probably thinks you want

```
var user;
answer = (x + "+" + y);
```

which would make perfect sense.